# How do I spyOn a function defined in the link function of a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I want to add spyOn in a function defined inside the link function of a directive. I tried spyOn(element, function_name) after compiling the element, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Functions defined inside a directive link functions are not available outside, they are inside the link function's closure, you cannot access it. You can instead test the template. Or if they are non DOM modiying stuffs have a controller for the directive and test that controller. Or if that is a common functionality, then abstract them to utility service/factory and test them.

Comment: I am testing the template, I just wanted to mock one particular function declared inside the link function of the directive.

Comment: You really don't mock a function you generally mock a dependency and its methods. Did you mean spy? even if that is what you meant you really cannot do that if they are defined in the closure as far as i know.

Comment: I'd just like to add to what @PSL said by pointing out that whenever you find yourself having to mock/spy on a function that is not visible outside of the thing you're trying to test it's usually a sign that either the test or the code could use some improvement. It's hard to tell which one it is here since you didn't include any sourcecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose the function on the directive's scope.

```
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    // this can be spied on
    scope.myFunction = function () {

    };

    // this won't be able to be spied on
    function myPrivateFunction () {

    }
}
```

Retrieve the directive's scope.

```
var directiveScope = angular.element('#myElement').scope();
// or .isolateScope() for isolate scope directives
```

Spy on the function.

```
spyOn(directiveScope, 'myFunction');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using an isolateScope

```js
//--directive.js--//
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('module')
    .directive('directive', directive);

  directive.$inject = ['dv'];

  function directive(dv) {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      replace: true,
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {

        bindto: '=bindto'
      }
    };

    return directive;


    function link(scope, element, attrs) {


      scope.generate = generate;

      scope.generate();

      function generate() {
        /**
         * Generate code goes here
         **/

      }
    }
  }
})(angular);

//--directive.spec.js--//
describe('Unit Test: Line-chart directive', directiveTest);

function directiveTest() {

  var dvFactory;
  var $compile;
  var $scope;
  var element;
  var compiledElement;
  var $isolateScope;

  beforeEach(module('module'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _dv_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    dvFactory = _dv_;

    element = '<directive></directive>';
    
    //Compile the directive element
    compiledElement = $compile(element)($scope);
    
    //Obtain an isolateScope of the compiled element
    $isolateScope = compiledElement.isolateScope();
  }));

  it('should call and spy on generate', function() {
    //spyOn a generate() in $isolateScope
    spyOn($isolateScope, 'generate').and.callThrough();
    
    //Call the method
    $isolateScope.generate();
    //Check it is called
    expect($isolateScope.generate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

}
```